# Integrity constraint violation when deleting entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got four entities Client, ClientAccount, ClientProductAccount and ClientProduct. Client contains the set of ClientAccounts and ClientAccount contains a set of ClientProductAccount, ClientProductAccount has a reference to ClientProduct. Client has also a set of ClientProducts. What I'm doing is deleting ClientProduct so what I need to do is to delete ClientProductAccount with given ClientProduct and then delete ClientProduct from Client. 
After this process I get

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key
>   no action; FK_7DMBVW6DMUIW2SFWLAQPS42HQ table: CLIENTPRODUCTACCOUNT

So far I checked the behaviour when I only delete ClientProductAccount and it deleted that entity and the result sql was:

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ClientProductAccount 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
```

On the other hand when I added next part of task to delete ClientProduct from Client Entity I'm getting that exception with integrity constraint violation and the following sql commands:

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        ClientProductAccount 
    set
        version=?,
        accountPriority=? 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ClientProduct 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
```

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Client {
        ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<ClientAccount> accounts = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<ClientProduct> products = new HashSet<>();
        ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ClientAccount {
        ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientAccount_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    Set<ClientProductAccount> productOfAccountSet = new HashSet<>();
        ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ClientProductAccount {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientProduct_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    ClientProduct product;
        ...
}
```

and ClientProduct:

```
@Entity
public class ClientProduct {
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = CommonColumns.ENUM_LENGTH)
    ProductType productType;
    ...
}
```

Code responsible for deletion:

```
        Set<ProductType> toBeDeletedProductsSet = client.getProducts().stream()
                .map(ClientProduct::getProductType)
                .filter(productType -> !productTypeList.contains(productType))
                .collect(toSet());
        client.getAccounts().forEach(
                clientAccount -> clientAccount.getProductOfAccountSet().removeIf(
                        clientProductAccount -> toBeDeletedProductsSet.contains(clientProductAccount.getProduct().getProductType())
                )
        );

        client.getProducts()
                .removeIf(clientProduct -> !productTypeList.contains(clientProduct.getProductType()));
```

The result should be that ClientProductAccount for given ClientProduct should be deleted and ClientProduct from Client Entity should be deleted as well. But I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation:
>   foreign key no action; FK_7DMBVW6DMUIW2SFWLAQPS42HQ table:
>   CLIENTPRODUCTACCOUNT  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.performReferentialActions(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.delete(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hsqldb.StatementDML.executeDeleteStatement(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getResult(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)    ... 63 more

Comment: could you please post the entity class ClientProduct as well?

Comment: Updated with ClientProduct entity

Comment: It seems you have unidirectional one-to-many ClientProduct to ClientProductAccount. have you tried  CascadeType.DELETE on the  '@ManyToOne' definition inside the ClientProductAccount ?

Comment: I've tried this solution but it didn't work.